# How can I remove items from start menu on Ubuntu 14.04 Flashback?

Tags: 14.04, menu, gnome-classic

I tried `alacarte` with no luck.

I also tried: `To remove the Dasher menu item from the Accessories submenu, edit /etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu, by adding the following before the final``tag in the file`.

and I searched `dconf`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is - you can not, it is hard-coded. To remove it you will need to modify gnome-panel source code.